# Passing data to components via subscription method

Tags: angular

I tried to pass data from my Newproducts component(parent component) to Newcard component (child component) via subcription but when i try to console log the data by clicking on the save button i dont see anything...the second time i click on save button then the data is displayed on the console log

Newproducts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-products',
  templateUrl: './new-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-products.component.scss']
})
export class NewProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  default = "Bread";
  values;
  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private prservice: Productservice) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onsubmit() {
    this.values = this.form.value;
    this.prservice.productcard.next(this.values);
    // console.log(this.form.value)
    // console.log(this.values)
    this.router.navigate(['card'], { relativeTo: this.route })
  }
}
```

Newcard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-card',
  templateUrl: './new-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-card.component.scss']
})
export class NewCardComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private prservice: Productservice,
              router: Router,
              route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.prservice.productcard.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        const cardvalue = value;
        console.log(cardvalue);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Products.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class Productservice {
   productcard = new Subject<[]>();
}
```

Comment: The component makes the subject emit a new value. The subject notifies all its listeners. Then the component navigates to the card component. And the card component then initializes and subscribes to the subject: it's too late; the value has already been emitted. Passing data using subjects between two routed components is usually a big smell. Pass data using URL parameters. Typically a component submits the orm to the server, gets back the ID of the saved object, and passes that ID in the URL to the next detail component displaying the new object, for example.

Comment: Another option is to make it a simple property, instead of a `Subject`. It will then retain its last value. Set that value from the first component and read that value from the second component. I have an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simpleservice-deborahk

Comment: Hey @JBNizet, can you provide any more information about this: `Passing data using subjects between two routed components is usually a big smell.`? I have a client that uses a `Subject` for *every* property and I'd like some more specific information on why that may not be the best idea. Thx.

Comment: @DeborahK I think the problem occures when you try to "save" a state of the application. If you base everything on subject change or other types of saving/caching data in services, if you close application ( lets say by mistake), you will lose everything. You could cache that in localstorage but still that data isn't necessary valid, especially if multiple people can edit data in the application. But this isn't necessary to have for every functionality/component of course. It all depends on what you want to achieve / what component does.

Comment: @DeborahK If the information a routed component must display is provided by an in-memory subject populated by a previous component, refreshing/bookmarking the page will fail: the app will star from scratch and the component won't know what it needs to display.

Answer (score 2):

Please use better code formating before you post this.

Its hard to get around that code. Anyways if your `card` route activates the child component. Then the problem is that you pass a new value to the subject before the child component is created. And because of that child component is unaware of "subject" change, because it didn't happen after the subscription.

Normal `Subject` works like this. You have to subscribe to subject before it changes else it won't give you any value if subscription occures after!

You should use `BehaviorSubject`. The difference here is that `BehaviorSubject` always holds a value. And when someone subscribes to it. It will emit the last value it held.

Hope I answered to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't nee this Productservice, all you need is to pass value to the child component using `@Input()` binding.

Read more about this in docs [Pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

Then in your child component you must implement `NgOnChange` interface and the `ngOnChange()` method will be called each time a value of the attribute decorated with @Input() has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is potential that @Ales answer is correct however, assuming that your child component is created before the shared service emits a new value on its subject via the parent then you could have a dependency instance bug.

your service is created when you provide it if you are using this syntax then the service ensures it is a singleton (i think).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: UserModule,
})
```

however with this syntax at a module level it is possible to have multiple service instances active that different components use therefore different subjects to subscribe to

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [UserService],
})
```